# IPA Export Using XCodebuild and shell script

Tags: ios, shell, provisioning-profile, ipa, xcodebuild

I've been searching for long time for a way to export IPA using Xcodebuild and shell script , all i found was an old code and even XCodebuild error aren't understandable for me . Please if there's one who  have tried to do this and found a solution for it , that will be awesome and helpfull

PS: In fact i've found a solution this script to generate IPA

THIS IS MY CODE

```html
xcodebuild clean -workspace "${WORKSPACE_ABSOLUT_PATH}" -scheme "${SHEME_NAME}" -configuration Release

###Cleaning XCodeproj(Without Pods)

xcodebuild clean -project "${PROJECT_ABSOLUT_PATH}" -scheme "${SHEME_NAME}" -configuration Release

####Setting (Prod) Boolean value



#echo -n "" >"${PLIST_CONFIGURATION_NAME}"
##
#echo "Prod boolean value is  $8"
##
#echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"><plist version="1.0"><dict><key>Prod</key><${PROD_BOOLEAN_VALUE}/></dict></plist>" >> "${PLIST_CONFIGURATION_NAME}"
##
#head "${PLIST_CONFIGURATION_NAME}"
#
#
###Preparing Archive (Generate .xcarchive file)
##
xcodebuild archive -workspace "${WORKSPACE_ABSOLUT_PATH}" -scheme "${SHEME_NAME}" -archivePath "${ARCHIVE_ABSOLUT_PATH}"
##
#
##Export Archive file (.xcarchive) to (.ipa) file
#
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "${ARCHIVE_ABSOLUT_PATH}"  -exportPath "${IPA_ABSOLUT_EXPORT_PATH}" -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile "${PROVISIONING_PROFILE_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Xcode 8.3 , you will not be able to select provision profile for the ipa...
see if this tool helps you
https://github.com/johnny77221/export-IPA